# KMM Image manupilation for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way, but I'm really struggling to get this right or even get examples on the net.

So I want to create a KMM (Kotlin Multi Platform) library to use in my Android and iOS app.

In the Common section I want to either load a local image resource or create a new image and manipulate it, say write some text on it or draw a line on it.

Then I want to expose that image in the Android specific part to android and I want to expose that image in the iOS specific part to iOS.

So, some very basic pseudo code:

```
KMM
  Common
    fun loadLocalImageResource(): Image {...}
    fun createNewImage(): Image {...}

  Android
    fun getLoadLocalImageResource(): Image {return loadLocalImageResource()}
    fun getCreateNewImage(): Image {return createNewImage()}

  iOS
    fun getLoadLocalImageResource(): Image {return loadLocalImageResource()}
    fun getCreateNewImage(): Image {return createNewImage()}
```

Thanks